# Converse of Schwarz' theorem

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

The theorem of Schwarz states, that for a function with continuous second order derivatives, we find that the partial derivatives commute. I am quite convinced that the converse shouldn't hold, i.e. that the second order derivatives need not be continuous, even if they commute, but I can't seem to find a counterexample, since there is only one example going around of a function with non commuting second partial derivatives:
$$f(x,y)=xy\frac{x^2-y^2}{x^2+y^2}, \quad f(0,0)=0.$$
My idea would be to find a different function where the derivatives are also $-1$ and $1$, then subtract the two functions and find that now the second partial derivatives are both $0$, hence commute, but are still not continuous (which still needs to be proven). Is this approach valid? Am I even correct in assuming that I have to disprove the statement?

Thanks for any input!